# swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I am using `ZFS` to receive some datasets around 60GB:

```
bzip2 -c -d mail.bz2 | zfs receive -F tank/jails/mail
```

Almost before finishing I start to get this error multiple times:

```
swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer: bufobj: 0, blkno: 16888849, size:4096
swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer: bufobj: 0, blkno: 16867303 size: 8192
swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer: bufobj: 0, blkno: 16888849, size:4096
swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer: bufobj: 0, blkno: 16889145, size: 12288
```

The `blkno:` repeats constantly

In a try to fix it I added a swap on ZFS:

```
zfs create -V 64G -o org.freebsd:swap=on -o checksum=off -o compression=off -o dedup=off -o sync=disabled -o primarycache=none tank/swap
```

And then enabled it:

```
# swapon /dev/zvol/tank/swap
```

The output of `swapinfo -h` is :

```
> swapinfo -h
Device          1K-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
/dev/zvol/tank/swap  67108864      77M      64G     0%
/dev/ada0p2       2097152      76M     1.9G     4%
/dev/ada1p2       2097152      76M     1.9G     4%
Total            71303168     229M      68G     0%
```

But after a while the server becomes unresponsive.

Any idea about how to fix this and what exactly does the `swap_pager` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the defined swap on the `/etc/fstab` and only using the new one created within the ZFS pool did the trick:

```
# swapinfo
Device          1K-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
/dev/zvol/tank/swap  67108864        0 67108864     0%
```